# Let M be some (unspecified) 4x8 matrix. The following row operations are applied in order to M:

Tags: linear-algebra

Let M be some (unspecified) 4x8 matrix.
The following row operations are applied in order to M:

1. Swap the second and third rows.
2. Multiply the fourth row by 3.
3. Subtract twice the fourth row from first.
4. Swap the first and third rows.
5. Add 3 times the first row to second.
6. Multiply the second row by -1.
   Let N be the result of applying these operations to M.
   part (a) There is a unique 4x4 matrix A such that A*M = N. Find it.
   part (b) The matrix A from the previous part is invertible. Find A^(-1).
   part (c) The matrix A^(-1) is invertible, so it can be written as a product of elementary matrix. Find such an expression.

I did my best.
I believe that A*M=N, so

```
A * M * M^(-1) = N * M^(-1)
A * I = N * M^(-1)
A = N * M^(-1)
```

so, i think A would be the identity matrix because N is the inverse of M. so `N = M^(-1)`

Is my assumption correct? Cause if I get part A, I would be able to do part B and C too myself.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks alot

Comment: $M$ is a $4\times8$ matrix - it is not invertible.

Comment: oh, I did not notice that at all. Can you please give me some hints on how to solve it then?

Comment: $A$ is the result of applying the given row operations on the identity matrix $I_4$